# How to extract part of knockoutArray with ko.computed

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I have an knockout array:

```
Tags = ko.observableArray()
```

which is filled with Tag-objects:

```
Tag = function(data){
    var self = this; 

    self.Id = data.Id;
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    self.Type = ko.observable(data.Type);
    self.ParentTextId = data.TextId; 
}
```

The Tags belongs to a Text-object:

```
Text = function(data){
    var self = this; 

    self.TextId = data.TextId;
    self.Title = ko.observable(data.Title);

    **self.Tags = ko.observableArray();**

    self.TagsOfType1 = ko.computed( function () { 

        //???

    } );

    self.TagsOfType2 = ko.computed( function () { ??? } );
    self.TagsOfType3 = ko.computed( function () { ??? } );

}
```

New instances of both the Tag and the Text object is created with results from a $.getJSON-query to the database. After getting the Tags. I assign the Tags according to their "ParentTextId".

Thing is: I need an array of each Tag.Type for my text, and thought that this must be possible to do with a ko.computed function on the Text-object, as this would make saving easier to handle with an "isDirty" prototype attribute.

But how should I set up the computed functions?

(Thanks in advance for any help. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ko.utils.arrayFilter` method](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) to filter your `Tags` array by type (or by any other predicate).

Then I would create a helper a function which takes a TagType and returns the computed containing the filtering:

```
self.Tags = ko.observableArray();

function createTypeComputed(tagType){
    return ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Tags(), function(item) {
            return item.Type() == tagType;
        });
    });
}

self.TagsOfType1 = createTypeComputed('tagtype1');
self.TagsOfType2 = createTypeComputed('tagtype2');
self.TagsOfType3 = createTypeComputed('tagtype3');
```

If you anyway have a fix set of TagType's you can even make it shorter and call the `createTypeComputed` in a loop defining your TagsOfType1, TagsOfType2, etc. properties dynamically.

Comment: Thanx again, nemesv. Just what I needed. Not sure if I understood the comment about the fixed set of TagType, but the code example will do. Brilliant! :D

Comment: I forgot about something: I need the dependency to be two ways; i.e. that if a tag is added (or removed) from self.TagsOfType1 (or 2 or 3), self.Tags also is computed and updated according to that change.

Since Tags is already defined and in use, how do I do that?

Comment: In this case you should not remove from the `self.TagsOfType1 (or 2 or 3)` arrays but you should look up your item and remove form the `self.Tags` array and the `self.TagsOfType1 (or 2 or 3)` will be update themselves.

Comment: @AsleG here is a fiddle with some sample code for the remove: http://jsfiddle.net/2XsJw/. So the key is that you never directly manipulate your computeds but the underlying datasource `self.Tags` and your computeds will reflect the changes automatically.

Comment: I see. But what i am trying to do is to have 3 different <input> fields of tags displayed with the "select2" plugin, while in the database (and view model) I only want to maintain one Tags-array with all the different types of tags. 
(You can think of the tagtypes as "Managers", "Locations", "Employees" and I want to use these tags for both searching and filtering.) 
Does that make sense?

Comment: It somewhat makes sense but a jsfiddle containing all this new details would help a lot, anyway we are now so far from your original question that I think you should create a new question with all this new information and create a jsfiddle with all this selects and inputs...

Comment: I agree. What I struggle with is creating those fiddles simple enough and also containing the database structure. (I´m using DNN7.1 and it´s DAL2 structure to communicate with the db.) I check this question as solved and see if I can formulate a new with all this in… :-o ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44163/discussion-between-asle-g-and-nemesv)

Comment: Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/p6zVR/2/ 
Why does a tag with "object Object" appear in the managerTags input field?